# How to disable Community Poll from Magento?

Tags: php, magento

How can we disable  Community Poll from Magento admin panel, without changing in layout.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got to admin panel `system > configuration` go to `advanced` tab  and disabled the `Mage_Poll`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To disable a specific poll:

1. In the backend, go to CMS -> Polls.
2. Open the poll you want to disable.
3. Change status to closed.

To disable poll functionality in general:

1. Go to system -> configuration -> advanced -> advanced -> disable modules output.
2. Disable Mage_Poll.

Comment: I am sorry I just do upvote for you. @Qaisar answer is more suitable for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the two previous answers work almost all the time, but I've just had one shop where even though the Poll extension was properly disabled, a poll would show up on some category pages. So in addition to disabling the Poll extension I've also had to empty all DB tables starting with "poll_", to get rid of Magento's example polls.